# How to create web form from a given xml schema, such that user can input the data in the webform and its xml will get generated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to create a webform according to an xml schema such that user can fill the form and get the corresponding xml data. Are there any direct way in Visual studio 2013. I know there are ways to make a webform from a database model directly in visual studio but not sure how to do this?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could edit your question to include an example of such an xml. Afaik, there's no way to auto-generate it.

Comment: there are ways to convert the xml into classes in Visual studio https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548(v=vs.110).aspx .. And there are ways in which database model to webform can be directly generated. So I am wondering if there is any hacky way to generate the xml inputer webform from xml schema without too much effort.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that. I thought you referred to using ASP.NET WebForms but I assume you're referring to "a web form" instead and are using MVC?

Comment: in case you're using MVC, there are tons of resources to get you started, e.g. [here](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/dynamic-forms-with-asp-net-mvc-and-xml/)